# ReactJS Formik, Why is the form not clearing?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have Form

```
const TextForm = props => (
  <Formik
    initialValues = {{
      text: '',
      target: props.target
    }}
    onSubmit = {(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
      if (values.target == 'add') {
        Request('POST', {"text":values.text});
        resetForm({"text":""});
        setSubmitting(false);
      }
    }}
  >
    {({
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        values,
      }) => (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="hidden" name="target"/>
        <textarea className={styles.text} value={values.text} name="text" onChange={handleChange}></textarea><br/>
        <button type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    )}
  </Formik>
);
```

And data send ok. But the form doesn't clear. Why??

I also try this:
TextForm.setFieldValue('text', '');
But this doesn`t work too.

Comment: @DacreDenny Thanks! It decide my problem

Comment: you're welcome. I've included an answer with suggested improvements that you might consider as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check that the following function call is not throwing an exception:

```
Request('POST', {"text":values.text});
```

If an exception is being thrown from `Request(..)`, then the subsequent call to `resetForm(..)` and `setSubmitting(..)` will be skipped which would be the reason for the problem you're experiencing.

Also, some improvements you might consider would be to make the following changes to your `onSubmit` handler:

```js
/* Define onSubmit callback as async */
onSubmit = { async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {

    try {

        if(values.target == 'add') {

            /*
            If request is async or returns a promise, wait
            for it before resetting form 
            */
            await Request('POST', {"text":values.text});

            resetForm({"text":""});
        }
    }
    /*
    If you want to handle errors here, do so with a 
    catch block like so:

    catch(err) {
        handleErrorHereIfYouChose(err);
    }
    */
    finally {
        /* 
        Always ensure form submit state is reset, even if
        unhandled is exception thrown 
        */
        setSubmitting(false);
    }
}}
```

Comment: I deleted my function "Request" and replace her called to fetch
`onSubmit = {async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
      try {
        if (values.target == 'add') {
          await fetch('http://localhost:3000/notes', {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({"text":values.text}),
          });
          resetForm({"text":""});
        }
      }
      finally {
        setSubmitting(false);
      }
    }}`
And now the form is not cleared again

Comment: Is values.target ever set to 'add' ?

Comment: Yes. And the request is executed

Answer (score 0):

Me helped values.text = '';

```
onSubmit = {async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
      try {
        if (values.target == 'add') {
          await fetch('http://localhost:3000/notes', {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({"text":values.text}),
          });
          values.text = '';
        }
      }
      finally {
        setSubmitting(false);
      }
```